# How to create tcpSocket livenessProbe replacement for Azure Container Instances in Bash?

Tags: bash, azure, yaml, azure-container-instances

It seems that Azure Container Instances [does not have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml) a tcpSocket in its livenessProbe selection.

How should a replacement for it be created in Bash? (**netcat** or **nc** is not an option with current base container)

e.g. I have application running a TCP server in port 8777 and I can use following Bash command

```bash
timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8777'
```

to check that it is still running, but if I try to execute similar check in YAML

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/bash -c "timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8777'"
```

if fails with following error:

> Liveness probe failed: to exec in container: failed to start exec "fafa...": quest RPC failure: failed to run runc create/exec call for container b12de... with exit status 1: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash -c \"timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8107'\"": stat /bin/bash -c "timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8107'": no such file or directory: unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the command must be splitted to multiple parts. At least the following works

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - "/bin/bash" 
    - "-c"
    - "timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8777'"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Container Instances, You can make use of readiness probe as mentioned in this [MS Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-readiness-probe) and also Liveness probe as mentioned in this [MS Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-liveness-probe)

As mentioned in [MS Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-readiness-probe) you can create a yaml file with readiness-probe.yaml with the code below:-

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01 location: eastus name: readinesstest
properties:   containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld
      command:
        - "/bin/sh"
        - "-c"
        - "node /usr/src/app/index.js & (sleep 240; touch /tmp/ready); wait"
      ports:
      - port: 80
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      readinessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
          - "cat"
          - "/tmp/ready"
        periodSeconds: 5   osType: Linux   restartPolicy: Always   ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '80' tags: null type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroup
```

And Deploy it in Azure Container Instances by running this command in your CLI:-

```
az container create --resource-group rg-name --file readiness-probe.yaml
```

**Output:-** https://i.imgur.com/aYXTrdk.png

To Deploy Liveness probe you can create include the liveness probe in your existing YAML file or create a new one by referring the  [MS Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-liveness-probe)

**liveness.yaml:-**

```
apiVersion: 2019-12-01 location: eastus name: livenesstest properties:
containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/nginx/nginx:1.15.5-alpine
      command:
        - "/bin/sh"
        - "-c"
        - "touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600"
      ports: []
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
            command:
                - "cat"
                - "/tmp/healthy"
        periodSeconds: 5   osType: Linux   restartPolicy: Always tags: null type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

```
az container create --resource-group rg name --file liveness.yaml
```

**Output:-** https://i.imgur.com/aOEowsG.png https://i.imgur.com/QNqsQuf.png

Comment: I know about readiness probe and liveness probe. What I am trying to do is to execute the bash script as liveness probe.